# Make login fail in Devise so to show default error message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Using Rails and Devise. In the following code, I do a check whether user has already signed in with omniauth (check using `email` and `provider` fields). If yes, then I want to fail it with the default message. While the following code works, but I am calling the `devise.failure.invalid` message manually, which I don't prefer.

I want to call some existing methods in in Devise so that it would mimic failed login, so that I don't have to redefine things.

```
class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  before_action :check_omniauth_presence, only: [:create]

  private
  
    def check_omniauth_presence
      resource = resource_class.where(email: params[resource_name][:email]).where.not(provider: nil)

      if resource.present?
        auth_keys = resource_class.authentication_keys.first.to_s
        flash[:alert] = t("devise.failure.invalid", authentication_keys: auth_keys)
        redirect_to new_session_path(resource_name)
      end
    end
end
```

Here you see I redefine the `authentication_keys`, calling the translation manually. I tried `set_flash_message` (but it's still manual) and `warden.authenticate!(nil)` but didn't work.